# Find and replace text in file using JREPL.BAT

Tags: batch-file

I am using the JREPL.BAT done by Dave Benham however I am unable to figure out how to find and replace the following text.

**Text I want to replace**

```
{"errorCode":9002,"message":"HTTP request execution failed for URI [https://what-ever.domain.com/page-abc-...')
```

To be replaced by the same text but without any of the `"` symbol.

So after JREPL.BAT is used it should look like:

```
{errorCode:9002,message:HTTP request execution failed for URI [https://what-ever.domain.com/page-abc-...')
```

Comment: I think the problem here are the odd number of `"` symbols in the search string; try to escape the first one like `^"`...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated where the text is coming from. I'll assume the text is in a variable named STRING.

```
set "STRING={"errorCode":9002,"message":"HTTP request execution failed for URI [https://what-ever.domain.com/page-abc-...')"
```

You can use the `/S` option to use the STRING variable as input. Obviously the command line will have to be adjusted if the text is coming from somewhere else.

It is impossible to pass a `"` literal to a CSCRIPT (JSCRIPT) program. So an escape sequence must be used within the FIND argument.

You can use a standard regex hex escape sequence:

```
call jrepl "\x22" "" /s string
```

Or you can enable the extended escape sequences with the `/X` option and use the non-standard `\q` escape sequence

```
call jrepl "\q" "" /s string
```

Both escape sequences are described in the `/X` option documentation

```
jrepl /?/x
```

Comment: When one answers a question of his own product... I'm not sure if OP knows you're the actual creator of JREPL.